Connecting powerBI Desktop to AWS Athena using ODBC erroring
I'm trying to test connecting powerBI desktop to AWS Athena using an ODBC connection:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/odbc-v2-driver.html
I have installed the driver (windows 2.x Amazon Athena ODBC (x64) and tested it using access key credentials.
Successfully connected to: Athena engine version 3
Region: us-west-2
Catalog: AwsDataCatalog
Workgroup: xxxxx
Auth Type: IAM Credentials
When I connect to powerbi Desktop and go to:
Get data -> database - AWS Athena
and I enter the DSN and connect I get the error:
Details: "We cannot convert the value null to type Record."
If I 'edit' and enter the role name with the IAM role information I get from AWS after connecting I then get the error:
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] Required connection parameter is missing: role_session_name
But when I look at the configuration options in the ODBC I don't see a place to enter the 'role session name' nor do I know where I get this information.
I'm not sure if the issue is how I've tried to configure my PBI desktop odbc connection or the odbc connection itself.  I tried connecting excel to the AWS Athena data using the odbc and I can get to the Athena database, schema and see tables/views but when going to connect get the error:
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [AmazonAthena][S3ClientError]: ExceptionName: , ErrorType: 99, ExceptionMessage: curlCode: 60, SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue or other ways to connect pbi desktop to AWS Athena?  I know there is a connector that allows pbi server/service to connect to AWS data sources which we'll test later but like to see if using pbi desktop is an option.

Hi This is happening because in the ODBC Simba Athena connector, verify SSL is enabled under advanced options, if you uncheck that option. The certificate issue would go.

